# Given a pointer to a member within a struct, how to return a pointer to this struct?

Tags: c

This is an interview question. I have no idea how to solve it.
could anybody help me:?

> Given a pointer to member a within a
>   structure, write a routine that
>   returns a pointer to the structure.

Thank you!

Comment: Although AndreyT is correct, the question is wrong. Given a pointer to a member and deriving the struct violates encapsulation in the worst way and will introduce unmaintainability. The "correct" answer is "don't, but if you are trying to see if I know a language wonk's hack, use `offsetof`. Strictly speaking, there is no guarantee that the address rendered by the pointer subtraction can be deferenced, so the selected answer is only right given conditions which may not obtain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, in order to pull that off you need to know the type of the enclosing struct `StructType` and the name of the member `member`. That must be a given. Without it, the problem has no solution.

Secondly, I don't know why other answers insist on reinventing the wheel (and engage into undefined and non-portable hacks on top of that) instead of using the standard `offsetof` macro. With `offsetof` the answer is

```
StructType *pstruct = 
  (StructType *) ((char *) pmember - offsetof(StructType, member));
```

Answer (score 5):

The Linux kernel code (GPLv2 licensed) includes a convenient `container_of()` macro:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

It is used like this:

```
static inline struct ext3_inode_info *EXT3_I(struct inode *inode)
{
    return container_of(inode, struct ext3_inode_info, vfs_inode);
}
```

@Richard's answer is excellent; the main difference is this code is parameterized to accept any `struct` and any member, and as a result is correspondingly more complicated.

Comment: Could you add a C version of the macro? As written it's ugly non-portable "GNU C" just for the sake of type-checking.

Answer (score 4):

Given a structure named `s` and a member named `m`

```
struct s * BaseS(byte *p)
{
     return (struct s *) (p - ((byte*) &(((struct s *)0)->m)));
}
```

The idea is to get the offset of the member and subtract that from the pointer.